# SQL Server Transaction Commits but results are missing

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, insert, transaction, varbinary

I am not sure how to describe the problem, so I will do the best I can and answer any questions.

My project is a Database Project for SQL Server 2008 (client dependent). Within that project I have a series of Seed Scripts that are compiled into a single sql script. The bulk of those seed scripts deal with inserting a large number of VARBINARY records (200MB+ worth of inserts). Since Visual Studio (and most other text editors) have trouble dealing with large files, I have the inserts logically split out into different files. Each file is wrapped in a transaction. The inserts themselves are constructor inserts.

The problem I have is each transaction commits without error. However I am getting the incorrect number of records in the finished database. Or the other effect I am seeing is zero records in the resulting table. While the scripts run, I see records inserted but once the script completes all the records are gone! So ... very confused. Any insight as to why I might be seeing this behavior would be great!

Each is laid out like e.g.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION AdBannerBlackEagle
PRINT N'BEGIN TRANSACTION AdBannerBlackEagle'

PRINT N'AdBanner BlackEagle English'

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ContentImageTemplateDetails]
    ([ContentImageTemplateId]
    ,[ContentImageTemplateDetailsCodeKey]
    ,[Data]
    ,[Checksum]
    ,[ContentType]
    ,[RegionID]
    ,[LanguageCode]
    ,[DisplayOrder]
    ,[CreatedDate]
    ,[ModifiedDate]
    )
VALUES
    (
        1,
        'AdBanner'
        ,0xFFD8FFE10018457869660000<reduced for brevity>
        ,'5F44C068DEE6507FDB01F52C9D66C291E06896DAACB2A6D687BDCE0EE3A5CE47'
        ,'jpg'
        ,5
        ,'en-DE'
        ,1
        ,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
        ,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
    ),
    (
        1,
        'AdBanner'
        ,0xFFD8FFE10018457869660000<reduced for brevity>
        ,'059FF9C3FCAF65EEDC01719D791AE88791C5C1A647BBC7F229A5F3FB0862D54D'
        ,'jpg'
        ,5
        ,'de-DE'
        ,2
        ,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
        ,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
    )
GO

COMMIT TRANSACTION AdBannerBlackEagle
PRINT N'COMMIT TRANSACTION AdBannerBlackEagle'
```

Comment: Check the value of @@TRANCOUNT after the commit in your example.  Committing nested transaction only decrement this count.  When a commit occurs and the count finally reached 0 - THEN the transaction is committed

Comment: Ok, cool I will take a look at that too. Might take me a minute to respond. I realized I should add more messaging around transactions that could become rolled back.

Comment: Nested transaction can be 'difficult' to debug.  I noticed you are naming your transactions.  Remember, you can SAVE a transaction with a name and rollback a 'named' transaction.  A rollback without a 'name' will roll EVERYTHING back to the outermost begin.  COMMITS decrement the @@TRANCOUNT.  When it reaches zero, the the ENTIRE transaction is committed - see this link for more information - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189336(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I am restructuring my transaction blocks to read something very similar to the below comment

Comment: `Declare @TransactionName varchar(255)
SET @TransactionName = 'Name'
Begin
 Begin Try

  BEGIN TRANSACTION @TransactionName
 -- code

  COMMIT TRANSACTION @TransactionName

 End Try
  Begin Catch
   DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000), @ErrorSeverity INT, @ErrorState INT;
   SELECT 
    @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
    @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
    @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

   RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, 
      @ErrorSeverity, 
      @ErrorState);
   Rollback transaction @TransactionName;
   Print @TransactionName + N' Rolled Back'
  End Catch
End
GO`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that:

> each transaction commits without error

I believe there is a nuance here that is being overlooked. The DML statement can cause an error and the `COMMIT` still happens (hence "nothing" is Committed) because this is not being done in a `TRY...CATCH` construct (and I assume that you are not setting `XACT_ABORT ON` at the beginning of the scripts). I believe that the DML statements are getting an error (possibly a truncation one?) but the Commit then runs and succeeds.

AND / OR:

Another possibility is that you have an unmatched `BEGIN TRAN` in one of the scripts (meaning, no matching `COMMIT`). Or how exactly are you running these scripts? If there is an open Transaction that is not committed by the time the scripts end, then the Transaction will be automatically rolled-back.

Individual DML / DLL statements, when executed outside of an explicit `BEGIN TRAN...COMMIT/ROLLBACK` are already their own Transaction and are automatically committed. Hence, you do not need `BEGIN TRAN...COMMIT` for single statements, unless you have some additional logic after the DML / DDL statement that conditionally decides on `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`. Also, unless you need the ability to discard portions of work that covers many statements within a single Transaction without rolling back the ALL statements, then you don't need to name them. It looks like you should start by removing the `BEGIN TRAN` / `COMMIT` / `ROLLBACK` statements, but still keep the `TRY...CATCH` statements that you are adding.

Comment: Finally was able to get through it. I added Try Catch blocks and added logic to rollback named transactions. This helped a lot with performance too!

Comment: So what was the actual problem causing the "missing" values? A mismatched `BEGIN TRAN`, truncation errors, or something else?

Comment: Silent rollback was unwinding the whole nested transaction.

Comment: Ah, ok. so that means "unmatched" `BEGIN TRAN`. Again, if you are only doing a single statement each time, I would rip the BEGIN TRAN / COMMIT / ROLLBACK out of it.

Comment: I wish I was! But the nature of the inserts were very large and for a long time I was running into memory issues during the insert.

Comment: So you have multiple INSERT statements within a single `BEGIN TRAN... COMMIT` ?